# How to group a PHP array by its elements length?

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array like:-

```
array("a","b","ab","xy","abc","xyz","abcd","abcde");
```

I want to group this array by value's length. So it should be like:-

```
  array(
    "1" => array("a","b"), //because there are two value which their lengths are = 1
    "2" => array("ab","xy"),
    "3" => array("abc","xyz"),
    "4" => array("abcd"),
    "5" => array("abcde")
  );
```

Than I want to reverse order by index;

Final output should;

```
array(
  "13" => array("13 length char"),
  "12" => array("12 length char"),
  ...
  ...
  "5" => array("abcde"),
  "4" => array("abcd"),
  "3" => array("abc","xyz"),
  "2" => array("ab","xy"),
  "1" => array("a","b")
);
```

After I used `krsort()` output is

```
Array(
[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => Abdülbari
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => ablefari
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => arakari
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => ari
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => ağari beğari
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => ağır erkeli muzari
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => Amerikanvari
        [1] => amudufıkari
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => abari
        [1] => abari
        [2] => Acari
        [3] => apari
        [4] => atari
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => abbari
        [1] => antari
        [2] => asgari
        [3] => asgari
        [4] => aşari
    )

 )
```

Array index should ordered from bigger index to lower index like: 20,14,12..

Comment: `foreach` and `strlen` is all you need. Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: You should be aware that this code, as well as the answer you've accepted, does not handle UTF-8 encoded string properly. Which has already lead to some subtle bugs in your output. I recommend taking a look at my answer, for a better example on how to write this bit of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$array = array("a","b","ab","xy","abc","xyz","abcd","abcde");

$final_array = array();
foreach ($array as $arr){
   $final_array[strlen( $arr)][] =  $arr;  //I have checked the  length of values and make it the key so that automatically your each value will go to corresponding length array
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/671126

Note:-  I have checked the  length of values and make it the key so that automatically your each value will go to corresponding length array

final output what you want:- https://eval.in/671137

Comment: I don't think posting only code without an explanation is a good choice, at least not in this case where I strongly suspect the question is a learning exercise.

Comment: I edited my question for reverse order situation. I used `asort()` but it does not work properly. I think php handles index values as string. ()

Comment: @Anant when you run eval.in, it gives you performance info. You're running about 600 syscalls in `0.016ms` while I'm doing only 313 sys calls..

Comment: @Anant I've given two reasons: 1. code without explanation, makes it harder to learn the whys. 2. Complex and condensed code, makes it harder to understand the code, learn why it works, and can hide bugs. Please see my example for how to make things simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, quite easily, with a combination of `mb_strlen()`,`foreach()` loop, and a temporary array in which you use the length as the key.

Now, I'm not going to write out the code for you, as this strikes me very similar to a homework/test project. But if you take a look at the following links, they should help you get started:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

***Edit, added:***

Seeing as there have been a couple of answers already posting the code, I don't see any further harm coming from posting one myself.

```
/**
 * Groups the values based upon their length, and returns
 * an array sorted by descending order of length.
 * 
 * Note: This expects the values to be encoded with UTF-8.
 * 
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function group_values ($array) {
    // Create the temp variable to hold the sorted values.
    $tmp = array ();

    foreach ($array as $elm) {
        // First we need the length of the string, to use as the index for the grouping.
        $len = mb_strlen ($elm, 'UTF-8');

        // Add the element to the temp array, as a new element for the index key.
        $tmp[$len][] = $elm;
    }

    // Sort the array in reverse order, forcing a numerically comparison.
    krsort ($tmp, SORT_NUMERIC);

    // Return the finished array.
    return $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe just walk the array with a function that checks the length of a given value and assigns it to a group.

```
<?php
    $arr = [ 'a','b','ab','xy','abc','xyz','abcd','abcde' ];
    $groups = [];

    array_walk( $arr, function( &$value, $key ) use (&$groups) {
        $groups[ mb_strlen( $value ) ][] = $value;
    });
?>
```

You can see the running example **https://eval.in/671158**

Note you need at least PHP 5.3 to be able to inherit scope, with `use` keyword.

Also, there's no point in reversing the array. When you iterate as follows:

```
$count = count( $groups );
for ( $i = $count; $i >= 0; --$i )
    print_r( $groups[ $count - $i ] );
```

And you are printing them as ordered as well. Again, no need to abuse php functions just because they seem easier to write in.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to downvote this one, for the same reasons I downvoted Anant's answer. While your code is technically better, you still have all the same flaws in your answer as he does. Including the inability to properly handle UTF-8 strings. In fact, yours might be even harder to grock, seeing as you're using more advanced methods in the same condensed manner.